# How do airlines make sure that pilots remain skilled enough to operate aircraft? What quality assurance is there for certified pilots?

Tags: flight-training, commercial-aviation

What measures are in place to prevent pilots from being put in charge of passenger planes without an appropriate level of training and skill? Are these measures enforced equally by different countries, airlines and aviation authorities?

Answer (score 19):

Put quite simply for this answer - The Licence a pilot holds is the assurance that the pilot has received the appropriate level of training.

Each country has it's own standards for training, their own requirements, and their own limitations on the operation of that licence. In saying that, MOST countries standards are reasonably in-line in regards to Aeronautical Experience required to sit each flight test.

In Australia, the requirement to sit a Commercial Pilot Licence is a minimum of 200 hours Aeronautical Experience (150 hours if ALL training has been conducted on an Integrated Course, now to be recognized under Part 141). From there, there is a break down of what that 200/150 hours must consist of.

Now, having a Commercial Pilot Licence (again, speaking from an Australian point of view) does not give a pilot the right to sit in the left seat of an Airliner. You need further training such as;

- Multi-Engine Command Instrument Rating
- Type Endorsement (for the intended aircraft)
- Crew Resource Management Training
- Dangerous Goods Training
- Senior First Aid (Not mandatory, but common)
- Company, Emergency, Cyclic and Systems checks (per company)
- Air Transport Pilot Licence Theory Exams (in some cases, Airlines may not even look at you if you haven't completed these - In
  Australia, it is an unwritten must-have!)

And thats just to sit in as a Co-Pilot..

Captains need years of experience, and a lot more training and check to get into that coveted Left Seat.

So again, to bluntly answer your question, regardless of country, there is law in place that stipulates that Pilots must be appropriately trained to fly airliners.

Comment: You should also mention the recurrent training to make the answer complete.

Comment: Are you sure a CPL allows you to fly right seat on scheduled passenger service in Australia? This is certainly not the case here in the U.S. At least an ATP-r is required here and even then you usually have to start out on the regional carriers.

Comment: @reirab "usually have to start out on the regional carriers" makes it sound like you could be conflating legal requirements with industry/business common practices.

Comment: @Sparr Sorry for any confusion there. The ATP-r is a legal requirement. The "usually have to start out on regional carriers" is not a legal requirement, but is industry reality. The OP asked how pilot training is ensured by airlines, too, not just by laws.

Comment: It's true enough that there are laws in every country, but the legal, as well as practical, experience requirements to fly an airliner on scheduled passengers service varies dramatically between different countries. For example, ICAO has "Multi-Crew Pilot License" specification that is designed to allow relatively low-hour (i.e. starting at around 250 hr) pilots to fly SIC on an airliner, while, in the U.S., 750 is the absolute minimum requirement to fly SIC on an airliner (and that requires that you have additional previous experience as a military pilot.)

Comment: @JanHudec - The `Cyclic` component of `Company, Emergency, Cyclic and Systems checks (per company)` is where I was trying to hint at that point. :)

Comment: @reirab - Yes, you do not require an ATPL to sit in the right seat of an Airliner, as the hour and experience requirements in Australia are very high, and difficult to achieve in General Aviation. In saying that, all Australian airlines require any applicant to have all 7 ATPL exams completed, so that as soon as the flight requirements are met for at ATPL, a flight check is organised, and the Licence granted. 

Also in Australia, generally you pick an Avenue (International, Domestic or Regional) and from there remain in that catergory. There is no real progression from Regional to Jet.

Answer (score 1):

That is the function of a license. Every country has their own standards, and by international treaties most countries must respect the licenses issued by other countries. So, for example, a Malaysian pilot is allowed to fly in the United States, even though he has a Malaysian license and does not have an FAA license. For this reason, it may be slightly more dangerous to fly on foreign air carriers, especially if they are from sketchy, third-world countries.

Carriers have much different standards for who is allowed to captain an aircraft. For example, a big carrier like Delta will usuallly have tougher standards than a regional airline or a charter company, but not necessarily. You can find small charter companies with really tough standards, and others that will let much less experienced captains fly their aircraft.

Do not think that safety is purely a product of training and experience. You can find guys with 10,000 hours who do stupid stuff and make bumpy landings all the time and kids with 800 hours who fly ten times better than them. Skill does not necessarily = experience. Also, performance in a crisis has little to do with experience. Put one guy in a crisis and he might freeze up like a rabbit, and another cooly reacts with correct decisions. It's impossible to predict ahead of time.

In difficult situations often judgement is more important than skill or experience, although experience can help improve judgement. Examiners will try to test a pilot's judgement, but it is hard to do. It's an undefinable quantity. Once again, you can have a guy with 800 hours who has much better judgement than the long-timer Navy pilot with 10,000 hours. It's difficult to predict.

Comment: I have to disagree on some points here. Saying that flying on Foreign Carrier's is less safe than fly an American Carrier is really not true (I'm presuming your indicating American carriers by the FAA reference). Qantas in your statement above would be a foreign carrier, and according to the recently released stats and ratings for 2014, Qantas is the world's safest, and most experienced carrier, and in this case, experience relates directly to skill and safety. 
Included in that Top Ten listing where Airlines such as Lufthansa and Singapore, both foreign carriers.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I have to admit I tend to check airlines' safety records before I fly with them if they are not already known to me. I'm sure even the most lax are reasonably safe but as a nervous (yet frequent) flier I will take very safe over reasonably safe if given the option!

Comment: @JamesHam I said "sketchy third-world carriers", not Quantas. Yeah, and Swiss pilots are good too. Try flying Chanchangi Airlines in Nigeria sometime if you think foreign carriers are so safe buddy.

Comment: @Tom.  I assume that you take such precautions when choosing your mode of transport to the airport since that part of the journey is many times less safe than the most "questionable" of commercial airlines.  The only thing that would make me pause is if that airline is forbidden from flying in Aus/Europe/US.

Comment: According to [Airline safety rankings](http://www.jacdec.de/safety-ranking-2014/), the safest airlines are non-US airlines. There's also [Airline Ratings](http://www.airlineratings.com/safety_rating_per_airline.php) but that gives both Delta and Aeroflot the maximum score so has lower precision.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick The problem is that most of those 'rating' schemes are extremely subjective. The link you gave rated Malaysian Airlines above American Airlines. I think that says a lot about the quality of their rankings. Furthermore, from a brief glance at their website, it looks like they're using number of incidents directly rather than comparing it to the actual size of the airline. I don't know about you, but I'd feel a little better about flying on an airline that has had one incident in 10,000,000 cycles vs. one who has had 1 incident in 100 cycles.

Comment: @reirab their indexing takes into account [size of airline etc (e.g. Passenger Kilometers)](http://www.jacdec.de/about-safety-ranking/) but I couldn't find the exact formula (perhaps they consider it a trade-secret) *"Based on our annual safety calculations which include all hull loss accidents and serious incidents in the last 30 years of operations in relation to the revenue passsenger kilometers (RPK) performed in the same time. "*

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Ah, I overlooked that at first. It wasn't listed at all on the column translation image they have at the bottom of the linked page. At any rate, larger airlines with more flight cycles still end up getting penalized somewhat just because aviation accidents are so rare that most of the smaller airlines have never actually had a fatal accident. Even being the largest airlines in the world, none of the major U.S. carriers have had a fatal accident since 2001. The regional carriers have had some (still less total fatalities than Air France alone,) but the majors haven't had any.

Comment: @reirab. I guess my real point is that the answer lacks any data or references to support the (implicit) flag-waving. What data I can find (however debatable) doesn't either.

Comment: I wouldn't really call _"For this reason, it may be slightly more dangerous to fly on foreign air carriers, especially if they are from sketchy, third-world countries."_ flag-waving. I don't think his intent was to say that all non-U.S. airlines are less safe, just that some are (and especially the ones from third-world countries with less-than-strict aviation regulations/enforcement and generally less experience.) If I'm interpreting his intent correctly, it's pretty hard to argue that he's wrong. I would assume EU/Aussie/Kiwi carriers to be of similar safety quality as U.S. carriers.